# Mixed Embed Outputs Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js, embed

So I've made a couple of commands on discord.js and I got interesting yet confusing results, the embed outputs are all messed up like if I do a clear command It clears the messages but the embed results are the same as my ping command I tried to check my code but nothing seemed wrong here it is, I apologize if it's messy I don't know how to type properly, although the weird thing is that the part where the embed mix-up originated is just like the others, here is the code

```
(embed)
        .setTitle('Bot Latency:')
            .setDescription(`${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp} ms`)
            .addField('API Latency', `${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms`)
            .addField('Discord Status', `https://discordstatus.com/`)
            .setColor(0x008080)
        message.channel.send(embed);
```

Comment: Thats your ping embed, is this what you're sending on clear command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You for sure have multiple embeds with the same variable. That can be the reason of the problem. Try giving every embed another name such as for a ping command

```js
const pingembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
```

for a clear command

```js
const clearembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
```

and doing so for all embeds.